# DRY foreach loop with dynamic variable

Tags: php, nested-loops, nested-sets

I'm trying to figure out the best way to DRY a foreach loop. I need the loop to add the node into the tree array only if it has any children.

```
$categories = Category::all();

$nodes = $categories->toTree();

$tree[] = [
    'id' => null,
    'name' => '--No Parent--'
];

foreach ( $nodes as $node ) {

    $tree[] = [
        'id' => $node->id,
        'name' => $node->name
    ];

    foreach ( $node->children as $node2 ) {

        $tree[] = [

            'id' => $node2->id,
            'name' => $node->name.' > '. $node2->name
        ];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple `if` that checks for that condition would work for you.

```
$categories = Category::all();

$nodes = $categories->toTree();

$tree[] = [
    'id' => null,
    'name' => '--No Parent--'
];

foreach ( $nodes as $node ) {
    if ( is_array($node->children) && count($node->children) > 0 ) {
        $tree[] = [
            'id' => $node->id,
            'name' => $node->name
        ];

        foreach ( $node->children as $node2 ) {

            $tree[] = [

                'id' => $node2->id,
                'name' => $node->name.' > '. $node2->name
            ];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work for me as I need it to reiterate the foreach. Also notice that the second foreach has a the variable $node2

Comment: Could you show me what $nodes might look like? Do a var_dump? I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you want.If you could show a simplified version of a $nodes array and then what you would want it to display that would help me understand.

Comment: the $nodes variable contain a collection of category models. Collection {#795 ▼
  #items: array:91 [▼
    0 => Category {#798 ▶}

Comment: I just want to repeat the foreach if there happens to be a child relationship